# Ext JS - Version variable Increment

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

In my design, I have got a grid with the store XYZ. In grid I am showing following fields:

```
ID(Hidden) , Name, Address , Phone, Version
```

I have a button called Save.

Now this Grid has Cell editing enabled.

Now whenever user changes any Name and press Save, I have to send new Name, address, phone and incremented version back to database. So if version is 1.0.0 , I need to send it back as 2.0.0

Now whenever user changes any address and press Save, I have to send Name, new address, phone and incremented version back to database. So if version is 1.0.0 , I need to send it back as 1.1.0

Now whenever user changes any address and press Save, I have to send Name, address, new phone and incremented version back to database. So if version is 1.0.0 , I need to send it back as 1.0.1

Basically,

```
Name --> 1.0.0 to 2.0.0
Address --> 1.0.0 to 1.1.0
Phone --> 1.0.0 to 1.0.1
```

What willbe the optimal way to do such version increment? String parsing?

Any help in this matter will be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `validateedit` listener on the grid.**[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/u47)** is a working example.

```
listeners: {
            validateedit: {
                    fn: function(event,editor){ 
                        if(editor.value!=editor.originalValue){
                        var versions=editor.record.getData().version.split('.');
                        versions[editor.colIdx]=parseInt(versions[editor.colIdx])+1;
                        editor.record.set('version',versions.join('.'));
                       return true;
                    }
                 }
            }

        },
```